# Should I use | (pipe) or ? (question mark)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have grouping parentheses `()` and `(?: )` and I need to match even if the expression within the brackets does not match. I've seen both `|` and `?` used for this (i.e. `(a|b|c|)` and `(a|b|c)?`), but which should be used/is more efficient, and why?

As different JavaScript engines interpret regex differently, I'm specifically using the SpiderMonkey engine. A generalised (both language-wise and engine-wise) answer would be nice however.

Edit: A concrete example is the [DuckDuckGo Frequency goodie](https://github.com/duckduckgo/zeroclickinfo-goodies/blob/master/lib/DDG/Goodie/Frequency.pm#L9). Why did the author choose `|` over `?` in this case?

Comment: Can you post your current regex? I cant picture what you're trying to do..

Comment: A more concrete problem would be appreciated; these are two different operators that do two different things, either of which will be the most appropriate for any given context.

Comment: I think he wants to know if `(a|b|c)?` or `(a|b|c|)` is better/faster.

Comment: @ThiefMaster That is indeed what I'm asking. Sorry to anybody if I was confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check performance, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kN7FQ/).

---

#### Using `?` with grouping or `|` with empty string as an option may lead to unexpected results!

Couple tests:

```
var myString = "this is a test string"; 
var myRegexp = /(test)?/; 
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString); 
alert(match[0]); // returns empty string

var myString = "this is a string"; 
var myRegexp = /(test)?/; 
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString); 
alert(match[0]); // returns empty string

var myString = "this is a test string"; 
var myRegexp = /(test|)/; 
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString); 
alert(match[0]); // returns empty string

var myString = "this is a string"; 
var myRegexp = /(test|)/; 
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString); 
alert(match[0]); // returns empty string

var myString = "this is a test string"; 
var myRegexp = /(test)/; 
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString); 
alert(match[0]); // returns "test"
```

This one ends with error:

```
var myString = "this is a string"; 
var myRegexp = /(test)/; 
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString); 
alert(match[0]); // error
```

And this one might be a solution for you:

```
var myString = "this is a test string"; 
var myRegexp = /^(?:.*(test)|(?!.*test))/; 
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString); 
alert(match[1]); // returns "test"

var myString = "this is a string"; 
var myRegexp = /^(?:.*(test)|(?!.*test))/; 
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString); 
alert(match[1]); // returns undefined
```

Test the above code with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxndk/).

Comment: Luckily I'm using grouping as part of a larger regex. If the entire regex doesn't match, an `if (!match) ...` will catch those.

Answer (score 1):

From your description it sounds like the appropriate choice is the `?` quantifier, which directly allows a preceding group between parens to be matched optionally.

On the other end, `|` is used when you want to match *one out of a set* of patterns.